# Remove recycler view item from view holder

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview

I'm trying to remove an item from my `RecyclerView` when the user deletes a post but want to notify the adapter from inside the `ViewHolder` that an item has been removed.

Can someone help me with a code example?

Comment: please add some code to show what have you done till now and what you want to achieve

Answer (score 0):

When asking question please add some code of what you have done up to now. I think you are looking for this:

```
yourList.remove(holder.getAdapterPosition());
notifyItemRemoved(holder.getAdapterPosition());
```